# Does libuv cause memory leak in uv_listen()?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, libuv

I test my small program that uses libuv.

Program's debug output shows memory leak.

### condition

libuv version

```
#define UV_VERSION_MAJOR 0
#define UV_VERSION_MINOR 9
```

- os: windows 7.0
- compiler: vs2010

my test code

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <uv.h>

void on_new_connection(uv_stream_t *server, int status) {
}

int main() 
{
    _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);

    uv_tcp_t server;
    uv_tcp_init(uv_default_loop(), &server);

    struct sockaddr_in bind_addr = uv_ip4_addr("0.0.0.0", 9123);
    uv_tcp_bind(&server, bind_addr);

    // leak occurred here  
    uv_listen((uv_stream_t*)&server, 128, on_new_connection);   

    //uv_close((uv_handle_t*)&server, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

### result

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{56} normal block at 0x002A3258, 11136 bytes long.
Data: <T B             > 54 F8 42 00 09 00 00 00 CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD 
Object dump complete.
```

### internal leak location

call stack

```
uv_tcp_listen(...) 
uv_listen(...)
main(...)
```

code

```
uv_tcp_listen(...)
{
  ....
  if(!handle->accept_reqs) {
    handle->accept_reqs = (uv_tcp_accept_t*)
      malloc(uv_simultaneous_server_accepts * sizeof(uv_tcp_accept_t));  << 
  ....
}
```

Comment: Why is the `uv_close` commented out? Isn't that the thing that is supposed to clean up resources?

Answer (score 1):

uv_listen() indeed calls malloc() but it's not a leak. However if you close the server handle (and wait for the close callback) the memory will be freed again.

Answer (score 1):

With proper cleanup, `uv_listen` should not leak memory.  In this case, `uv_close` needs to be invoked, and the default loop needs to run to completion.

Calling `uv_close` will place the server into a closing state.  Once there are no more pending operations, an `endgame` is added to the loop for deferred invocation.  The `endgame` will be processed within `uv_run`, which will eventually free `accept_reqs` in [`uv_tcp_endgame`](https://github.com/joyent/libuv/blob/cc1c1912ca119c56ecdc0e4564720a01bd53d47e/src/win/tcp.c#L210).